# Django annotate field not passed to serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm a little frustrated about why this does not work.

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='groups')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='members')
    field1 = models.IntergerField()
```

View:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Group.objects.filter(members__user=self.request.user).annotate(field1=F('members__field1'))
```

Serializer:

```
field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_field1(self, obj):
    return obj.field1
class Meta:
    model = models.Group
    fields = ('field1', ...)
```

Getting the error *object has no attribute 'field1'*

However, using the same query in shell window successfully retrieves value for field1

```
g = Group.objects.filter(members__user=self.request.user).annotate(field1=F('members__field1'))
print(g[0].field1)
```

*Successfully prints field1 value*

Comment: And where is the `return` statement here? - `Group.objects.filter(members__user=self.request.user).annotate(field1=F('members__field1'))`

Comment: @Charnel sorry I transposed it and left it out by accident. It is there in the code.

Comment: How do you pass the queryset to the serializer?

Answer (score 0):

change the get_field1() method

```
def get_field1(self, obj):
    return obj.members.field1
```